# Quantum Circuit Properties typo (documentation bug?)

Tags: qiskit

Just to report that the notebook "[Quantum Circuit Properties](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jupyter/tutorial/fundamentals/4_quantum_circuit_properties.ipynb)" under the Tutorial uses a circuit named `qc2` but afterwards the sample code still uses the `qc` circuit rather than `qc2`.

Answer (score 3):

Great to see you are engaging with the tutorials! I have had a look and I think this is deliberate, I believe that `qc2` is only introduced to demonstrate one type of circuit. The notebook then goes on to create circuits `qc3` and `qc4` to demonstrate other concepts.

If you find any other bugs please report them to the [Git repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials) by creating a new `Issue`.